# Replace numeric index with custom index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    ip        name
 0  10.1.1.1  aa
 1  10.1.1.2  bb
```

I want to remove index column and set ip for index:

```
ip         name
10.1.1.1   aa
10.1.1.2   bb
```

reset_index() and df.index.name not working...

Comment: `df.set_index('ip')` - has been answered before.

Comment: need `df = df.set_index('ip')`

Comment: set_index('ip') not working . Because print df.index.name is None and df still has a third column

Comment: Assumming the dataframe is `df`, you can use

    `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`
    `df = df.set_index('ip')`

Comment: @akilat90 could you please write as answer for accepting this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't write an answer for this question now :( maybe because it has been marked as duplicate by @Zero

Comment: @Zero its not duplicated because your answer isn't complete

Comment: @Zero , akilat90's answer is true

Comment: @Zero its needed in my issue.

Comment: @TheNone -- Could you add output of `df.to_dict()` to the question please

Comment: Actually I get confused by this question.I have been try and can not figure out what does @TheNone mean. you want the follow ouput :
inline `ip     name
      111.192.168.1 `,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set desired and drop current:

```
df.set_index('ip', drop=True)
```

As it was pointed out in one of the comments, to make changes inplace you can use either:

```
df.set_index('ip', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

or

```
df = df.set_index('ip', drop=True)
```

Comment: set_index('ip') not working . Because print df.index.name is None and df still has a third column